# Why does |z| > 0,35 give an answer for the middle of the standard Normal model, instead of the tails?

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

I have a question in a textbook. It reads like:

> Assuming a standard Normal model, what is the probability for each of the following cases?

And the case is:

> |z| > 0,35

So I took this to mean any time z > 0,35 and any time z < -0,35. Which is basically the majority of the graph outside the center. My answer would have been 0,72634, but the book says the answer is 0,27366, i.e. the opposite. I don't get why the answer is for the middle of the range instead of the outside parts.

Comment: It's probably a typo in your book. Clearly the probability is greater than $1/2$. Your reasoning looks correct.

Comment: Minor nitpicking: any time z > 0,35 **or** any time z < -0,35